# Show Print Dialog before printing

Tags: c#, printdialog

I want to show the print dialog box before printing the document, so the user can choose another printer before printing.  The code for printing is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintImage);
                pd.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ToString());
            }
        }
        void PrintImage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.X;
            int y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Y;
            int width = this.Width;
            int height = this.Height;

            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);

            this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
            Point p = new Point(100, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);
        }
```

will this code be able to print the current form?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use `PrintDialog`

```
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
 pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
 PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
 pdi.Document = pd;
 if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     pd.Print();
 }
 else
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Print Cancelled");
 }
```

**Edited**(from Comment)

On `64-bit` Windows and with some versions of .NET you may have to set `pdi.UseExDialog = true`; for the dialog window to appear.

Comment: when press the button,print dialog does not open,but the messagebox displaying Print Cancelled is shown

Comment: @ user2257581:i test it now,it work,make a new application and test it again,see it work

Comment: On 64-bit Windows and with some versions of .NET you may have to set `pdi.UseExDialog = true;` for the dialog window to appear. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6385844/202010 for details.

Comment: @ThomasGerstendörfer where to write that code?
before the `if` statement?

Comment: @user2257581 Yes, just above or below the `pdi.Document = pd;` line.

Comment: Not sure why I am the only one experiencing this but pdi (PrintDialog) does not have a Document property for me...

Comment: @Shumii That's probably because you're using `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog` from `PresentationFramework.dll` whereas the answer refers to `System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog` from `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, the code should include a using directive

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

for further reference please goto
[PrintDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)