# How to print a form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to print a form. I have this code but I can't choose what printer to print and it prints with default printer. How can I resolve this?

```
void PrintImage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.X;
    int y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Y;
    int width = this.Width;
    int height = this.Height;
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(width, height);
    this.DrawToBitmap(img, bounds);
    Point p = new Point(100, 100);          
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, p);
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintImage);

    pd.Print();        
}
```

Comment: This looks like winforms, is that correct?  I would also recommend listing at least one solution that you've tried and why/how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15985978/3676570)

You have to use PrintDialog

```
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
 pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
 PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
 pdi.Document = pd;
 if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     pd.Print();
 }
 else
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Print Cancelled");
 }
```

On 64-bit Windows and with some versions of .NET you may have to set pdi.UseExDialog = true; for the dialog window to appear.

Comment: @user3810124 What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Or does it just don't show the dialog?